# Righthand side of Typescript intersection type is lost when mapping over array of that type

Tags: typescript

In the following code, when I try to use `Array.map` on a collection of objects of `MyType`, Typescript loses the right hand side of the intersection type (`{value: string}`). However, when I loop over the same collection with `for ... of` it tracks the types correctly. What's happening here?

(Typescript 5.0.2)

```
type MyType = {
  containers: {
    name: string;
  }[] & {
    value: string;
  }[]
}

const data: MyType = {
  containers: [{
    name: "name",
    value: "ddd",
  }]
}



for (const container of data.containers) {
  // This is fine
  const { name, value } = container;
}

data.containers.map(container => {
  // Property 'value' does not exist on type '{ name: string; }'.(2339)
  const { name, value } = container; 
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The way `myType` is defined it looks like an intersection of two arrays. Iinstead you want a single array which can hold object with both property `name` and `value` .

Change myType to

```
type MyType = {
  containers: ({
    name: string;
  } & {
    value: string;
  })[]
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8BQUoGMD2AdsAIYCWBEATgM4BcUAFJttgcQLYT3XCXkDmAbixQAvlABk6EdgBuxADYBXLlB58CQkaICUAbQC6GURgz4CPKABNiJenESQoqZrkIlyVOlD2vWHVQAiNk5AgBoZKHllIKs48O0jE1MMADM8SkZzS3MPCky8VOtbYgA6XLJ86h1pbAB6Oqh4AAtSaig2qFTPEWzgdCgQiDCoxRUxZzciSqphZJsScvcZmlL2YjAGCs9M5AA+WqgGqAAFSjxISlAoAHJolRvrPAh2gjx+iAAPNv7CKFAnDc0IMAtxeAJBGIbqUGAAmADM8IAnDpeoRLMChiN7tBxKhtvlIcYdEA)

Comment: I think you're correct, but I'd still like to understand why there's a difference between the two methods of interating over the array?

Comment: There is an open issue describing the problem: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41874

Comment: Thank you @majusebetter, I think that issue is describing my problem. I'm still unclear on exactly why the two iteration methods have different behaviours, but it does look like I'm Doing It Wrong (sort of, IMO if this can't be handled correctly by Typescript then it should be an error, not a valid type that only works sometimes...)